# Is there an UnTapped event equivalent to Tapped event for TapGestureRecognizer object?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using TapGestureRecognizer can I check when a Tap Starts and Ends?

Answer (score 1):

TapGestureRecognizer has been around for a couple of years now, and unfortunately, it's still very limited (meaning that only the full tap event is recognized). If you want to get the touch down and up events (start/end, press/release or whatever), you have a couple of options:

1. Write a custom renderer that takes care of those events on the platform specific code. Android and iOS are both perfectly capable of handling these events and they just need to be exposed to the Xamarin.Forms world.
2. Follow [the article](https://xamarinhelp.com/custom-gestures-in-xamarin-forms/) and [GitHub sample](https://github.com/adamped/sample-xf-gestures) from Adam Pedley, where he implements the events that you're looking for.
3. Take a look at [MR.Gestures](https://www.mrgestures.com/), which is a commercial Xamarin.Forms library that actually implements a whole lot of missing touch gestures, including the ones you're looking for. *Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with this project, and I have never used the library, nor do I know whether it works in the latest version, but I've heard good things about it in the past. Use at your own risk.*

Comment: I would also suggest using MR.Gestures library, I've used that one and it is really helpful in situations like that.