# How to change color or frame border when control inside it is focused?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want frame which decorates a control inside it to change border color if the control and frame is pressed/tapped on all platforms: UWP, IOS, Android. If I subscribe Frame to "Focused" event it works only on UWP, not on Android and IOS. Gesture recognizers does not have "untapped" event as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56812049/is-there-an-untapped-event-equivalent-to-tapped-event-for-tapgesturerecognizer-o). Visual state groups did not work on mobile platforms too. So it looks like I am left with an option to create renderers (something similar to [this article](https://www.xamarinhelp.com/custom-gestures-in-xamarin-forms/)), that I would like to avoid that or use a third party library like "xamarin community toolkit" but I did not manage to make it work.

```
            <Grid VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Frame Focused="frame_Focused" Unfocused="frame_Unfocused">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Black" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Green" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Green" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Black" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter>
                       
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Frame>

                <StackLayout>
                    <Label />
                </StackLayout>

            </Grid>
```

Comment: Did you test if ContentPresenter becomes focused on iOS and Android when you tap on the Frame? I suspect that it would, in which case it would be easy to change the frame color by using DataTriggers

Comment: I saw that ContentPresenter has "Focused" event but it does not trigger on any platform.

Comment: I am thinking maybe it is possible to check if a child of ContentPresenter is focused and based on that change frame border color.

Comment: So I did a quick test on Android - Focused event isn't raised from an image that's inside a frame, but does work on a Entry... this makes for a tricky solution.

I found this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a75d5fab-073a-4dfb-b086-d5d2726a1003/how-to-trigger-quotfocusedquotof-a-object-in-androidxamarinforms).

I don't know how complex your UI is, but the only solution I can think of is to implement it yourself. I.e. when you tap on an element it becomes "selected" and all other elements are "unselected". Not the prettiest solution, but can't think of anything better

Comment: I haven't tested, but if you wrap that Frame in a `ContentView`, are you able to detect focus on that view?

Comment: I had done a simple and test the frame. I found that the focused event also can be hit when I add a break point to it. It seems that the focused event had been remove from the frame and the layout.